# Выделяется ли тут запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

**Специально для Вас**, стоимость проживания будет ниже официальной цены гостиницы! 
Если ставится, то почему? Если не ставится, то почему?

Answer (score 1):

**Здесь возможны варианты,** например:

(1) *Специально для Вас стоимость проживания будет ниже официальной цены гостиницы!*

Простое предложение без обособления обстоятельства в начале предложения.

(2) *Специально для Вас: стоимость проживания будет ниже официальной цены гостиницы!*

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение, двоеточие обозначает предупредительную паузу, запятой будет недостаточно.